# Problems with python versions in ROS Melodic

Tags: python-3.x, ros, catkin

I was facing problems with some libraries which I needed to run in python3 in ROS MElodic, so I tried the following command to build the workspace with python3

```bash
catkin build --cmake-args \ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \ -
DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \ -
DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m \ -
DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
```

But now I am facing bigger problems with my basic libraries and I want to come back, but I don't know how.

If I try to use the following command:

```
catkin build -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7m.so
```

The workspace gives many errors with many packages abandoned. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide the error messages or the exact type of errors you encounter

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Melodic targets Python2.7, not Python3. You would either need to rebuild Melodic with Python3, which is known to cause problems and isn't recommended. Or, use a version of ROS that supports Python3 natively; for ROS1 the only distro that does is Noetic(Ubuntu 20.04).